# How to work with Grouped Responses (Event/Trial) in StatsModels Logistic Regression

Tags: events, binary, logistic-regression, statsmodels, trial

I'm starting with StatsModels, coming from Minitab. And I can't find the option to do a binary logistic regression with the response in event/trial format.

Here's a very simple example of what I'm saying:
I have the data like this, grouped by variables, with the number of events (number of ones in binary) in one side and the number of trials (number of zeroes and ones) in the other:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jp7yn.png)

Do you know how can tell this to StatsModels?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 1):

Logit and Probit are only defined for binary (Bernoulli) events, 0 or 1. (In the quasi-likelihood interpretation it can take any values in the interval [0, 1]).

However, GLM with family binomial can be used for either binary Bernoulli data or for Binomial counts.

see the description of `endog` (which is the statsmodels term for response or dependent variable) in
http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.genmod.generalized_linear_model.GLM.html

"Binomial family models accept a 2d array with two columns. If supplied, each observation is expected to be [success, failure]."

an example is here
http://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html

Comment: Thanks a lot!! That's what I was looking for!